# ImageButton opens list of images to select from

Tags: android, list, android-fragments, imagebutton

I am creating my first Android app using a Navigation Drawer, and such most of my pages are fragments. Each page will contain several ImageButtons.

My goal is for the user to click an ImageButton, and then be displayed a "popup" list of images with their respective names. When the user selects an image, the ImageButton's src should become that image.

Any tips on how I could achieve this? Thanks!

Here is one of my fragments:

```
public class FragmentAnubis extends Fragment {

View myView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.god_anubis, container, false);
    return myView;
}
```

And here is its corresponding layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="100">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageStarterItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ah_puch" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageRelic1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ah_muzen_cab" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageRelic2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/agni" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, remove unnecessary root LinearLayout.

I guess you use DialogFragment to show list of images. In onclick handler get image source and send it throw event bus - Rx event bus or GreenRobots Event Bus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

In source activity you can catch all events and set source to first button

Comment: Thanks! Started using DialogFragments and they've worked great